# index new document and get the indexed document in the same query

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

it is possible to index a new document and return him after he succeeded indexed?

I tried to take the _id that returns but I'm using 2 queries and the index action takes some time and the second query not find the _id so it not always doing it perfectly.

this is the query that index the document:

```
const query = await elsaticClient.index({
routing: "dasdsad34_d",
index: "milan",
body: {
  text: "san siro",
  user: {
    user_id: "3",
    username: "maldini",
  },
  tags: ["Forza Milan","grande milan"],
  publish_date: new Date(),
  likes: [],
  users_tags: [1,5],
  type: {
    name: "comment",
    parent: "dasdsad34_d",
  },
},
```

});

Comment: So you encounter a "delay" between indexing a document and query for that document by its id afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

No, its not possible with default behavior. By default, Elasticsearch has only a near real time support. Its default refresh interval is 1 second as index refresh is deemed as a costly operation.

In order to overcome this, in your indexing operation, you can add **refresh=true**. You can get further details from below links.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html

Please note that this is **NOT a recommended** option as this comes with huge overhead. Only use this, if your inserts into this index in question are having a very very low number.

Recommended way is to use **refresh=wait_for** on your indexing operation. But this has a downside of waiting for a second for the natural refresh to complete. So if you have default refresh interval set to 1 and are okay with this as an acceptable trade off, then this is the way to go.

However, if you have a higher refresh interval set, then the wait time for the indexing operation will be as high the refresh interval. So choose your option carefully.